# How to unify a number of separate latex articles into a thesis?

Tags: macros

I am about to compile a number of different published articles into a single thesis. While each document on its own can compile and produce a PDF, there are several macros files  (shorthands for various formulas) that are inconsistent between them. Is there any way to do this with the least amount of change to each latex document? In particular, is there a way to include the macros "locally" for each article so that they don't conflict?

Comment: Why not just load the generated individual pdfs in the thesis via the `pdfpages` package? Since articles should be reproduced as they are, without changes, anyways.

Comment: To answer your question, macros defined inside an environment or group are local to the environment or group (`\begingroup` `\endgroup` or `{}`).  OTOH, ererything after `\end{document}` will be ignored.

Comment: pdfpages does not preserve hyperlinks. ||  We'd need to know about your workflow and about the intended merging/concatenating of the documents. E.g.: Will the contents of the single articles be subsections of the thesis so that section-headings of articles are to go into the thesis' table of contents? Will the macro-tokens whose definitions differ between articles end up in moving arguments?  ...